# C# Combine two lists with nested lists into one using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of the following structure in c#. Each name in <> is a list. I want to join those two lists into one `List<Server>`. The following pseudo code displays two such lists and how the result should look like:

```
<Servers>                           <Servers>
+...                                +...
+-- Server A,1                      +-- Server A,1
|       +...                        |       +...    
|       +--<Maps>                   |       +--<Maps>
|           +--Map x                |           +--Map x
|               +...                |               +...    
|               +--<Times>          |               +--<Times>
|                   +--Time i       |                   +--Time l
|                   +--Time j       |               +--<Jumps>
|               +--<Jumps>          |                   +--Jump t
|                   +--Jump s       |                   +--Jump u
|           +--Map y                |           +--Map z
|               +...                |               +...
|               +--<Times>          |               +--<Jumps>  
|                   +-- Time k      |                   +--Jump v
+-- Server B,1                      +-- Server B,2
```

Result should be:

```
<Servers>
+...
+-- Server A,1
|   +...
|   +--<Maps>
|       +-- Map x
|           +...
|           +--<Times>
|               +--Time i
|               +--Time j
|               +--Time l
|           +--<Jumps>
|               +--Jump s
|               +--Jump t
|               +--Jump u
|       +-- Map y
|           +...
|           +--<Times>
|               +--Time k
|       +-- Map z
|           +...
|           +--<Jumps>
|               +--Jump v
+-- Server B,1
+-- Server B,2
```

I tried using full outer join with linq but the result was also not what I wanted, for reasons I didn't understand servers that had the same keys weren't matched and so I always had duplicates of the same server with different data. That's when I stopped trying to do it with linq and just used loops to merge the lists by hand.

The code below gives me the desired result list. For now I will use it until I find a better way to do it. Is there a simple/shorter way doing that with linq? Using lambda expressions?

```
  foreach (Server importServer in oImportList)
        {
            if (!CoreList.Contains(importServer))
            {
                CoreList.Add(importServer);
                continue;
            }

            Server coreServer = CoreList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Equals(importServer));
            coreServer.Name = importServer.Name;
            coreServer.KZTimerVersion = importServer.KZTimerVersion;
            foreach(Map importMap in importServer.Maps)
            {
                if (!coreServer.Maps.Contains(importMap))
                {
                    coreServer.Maps.Add(importMap);
                    continue;
                }
                Map coreMap = coreServer.Maps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Equals(importMap));
                coreMap.Jumps.Concat(importMap.Jumps);
                coreMap.Times.Concat(importMap.Times);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea. It looks like you just passed the nested `Join`s the wrong parameters! For example, in the `Maps` join you're trying to join `coreServer.Maps` and `oImportList`... I suspect this should be `coreServer.Maps` and `importServer.Maps`.

Comment: I was able to get the code working with your help but then I saw that the result was not the list I desired. It only contained elements which where in both list present.

Comment: Ah, sorry... I've only very rarely used `Join` so I got it mixed up. I've undeleted an answer using `GroupBy` and `Select` that might work for you. I deleted it before because I thought I was going on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

You might have been looking for `.Union`, but that doesn't deal with the nested lists so I don't think it's what you really need. I set up a full example--although the structure isn't the same as yours I think you can easily apply the core linq:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Map
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MapProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class MapProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static IEnumerable<Map> Merge(IEnumerable<Map> a, IEnumerable<Map> b)
    {
        return a.Concat(b)
            .GroupBy(map => map.Name)
            .Select(mg => new Map
            {
                Name = mg.Key,
                Properties = mg.SelectMany(v => v.Properties)
                    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                    .Select(pg => new MapProperty { Name = pg.Key })
            });
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var mapsA = new[]
        {
            new Map
            {
                Name = "MapA",
                Properties = new[]
                {
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Jumps" },
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Hops" },
                }
            },
            new Map
            {
                Name = "MapB",
                Properties = new[]
                {
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Jumps" },
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Skips" },
                }
            }
        };
        var mapsB = new[]
        {
            new Map
            {
                Name = "MapA",
                Properties = new[]
                {
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Jumps" },
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Times" },
                }
            },
            new Map
            {
                Name = "MapC",
                Properties = new[]
                {
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Jumps" },
                    new MapProperty { Name = "Skips" },
                }
            }
        };

        var mapsC = Merge(mapsA, mapsB);

        foreach (var map in mapsC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{map.Name}");
            foreach (var prop in map.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{prop.Name}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
MapA
    Jumps
    Hops
    Times
MapB
    Jumps
    Skips
MapC
    Jumps
```

`Merge` is the important bit. It first puts `a` and `b` all into one list, then `GroupBy` name forms groups of maps that have the same name. The `Select` takes each group and makes a new `Map` with the contents of all the `Maps` in that group (this is the merge!). Then I did the same thing to the new merged map's contents and group up `MapProperty`s and combine/merge them.

In your specific case you'll need a little more work and levels to merge everything. I'd suggest finding a way to make a `Merge` method for each level in the tree and call the next level's from each parent level so you don't end up with a **massive** linq chain.